# pySerial: port only work the first command

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyserial

I have a trouble with pySerial. The port can write and read the data only once.  When I type the same command, the port doesn't work and return nothing.  It's only work on first command.  The wxTerminal also only works the first command. Why the port can't command continuously?

EDIT: I am running Win7 64bit, Python 2.7.9 and pySerial 2.7

The code is here:

```
import time
import serial
import wx

def init_serial():         
    global ser          
    ser = serial.Serial()
    ser.baudrate = 115200
    ser.port = 3   
    ser.bytesize = 8
    ser.parity = 'N'
    ser.timeout = None
    ser.xonxoff = False
    ser.rtscts=False
    ser.dsrdtr=False
    ser.timeout = 1
    ser.open()          

    if ser.isOpen():
        print 'Open: ' + ser.portstr     

init_serial()
while True:
    cmd = raw_input('Type what you want to send:\r\n')
    ser.write(cmd.encode('ascii')+'\r\n')
    if cmd =='q':
        ser.close()
        print ser.portstr +' is closed'
        exit()
    else:
        bytes = ser.readline() 
        print ('Return: ' + bytes)
```

The result is here:

```
Open: COM4
Type what you want to send, hit enter:
RR 500                **command and work**
Return: CCW_OK        
Type what you want to send, hit enter:
RR 500                **command again, but it doesn't work**
Return:               **return nothing**
Type what you want to send, hit enter:
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Just an idea: Try to terminate your command either with only `\r` or only `\n`. Is local echo or remote echo used there? Is your command "RR 500" displayed locally when you type it, or echoed remotely and then displayed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by myself.
It's need to add ser.close(), ser.open(), and time.sleep(2) before command in the loop.

```
init_serial()
while True:
    ser.close()
    ser.open()
    time.sleep(2)  #at least wait for 2s 
    cmd = raw_input('Type what you want to send:\r\n')
    ser.write(cmd.encode('ascii')+'\r\n')
    if cmd =='q':
        ser.close()
        print ser.portstr +' is closed'
        exit()
    else:
        bytes = ser.readline() 
        print ('Return: ' + bytes)
```