# Pyserial send and receive multiple commands

Tags: python, router, pyserial

I'm working on a script to send a list of commands to a device and return the output.

When the device first boots up, it has a few prompts. I am able to get through the prompts.

However, after completing the prompts, when I try to send a command  the command isn't sent.

#### Commands

The `commands.txt` is set up like this:

```
200,
2,no
2,
```

The first line (`200`) is to let the device boot up.
The 2nd and 3rd lines answer 2 different prompts.

#### Issues

The issues come after these 3 inputs. The code runs and completes. Python prints out each of the commands. So the list is processed by Python. However, I don't think the device is receiving the commands.

In the log, the `\n` and `no` are written out, but none of the commands after it are. The commands do show when I use ser.inWaiting()

When I access the device through putty and run the commands through the console, everything works as expected.

Why aren't the commands going through?

#### Small update:

I read somewhere that python may be sending the commands to quickly, so I tried sending the commands 1 char at a time with a `.01` delay.

It still didn't work:

```py
for i in lines[1]:
   cmd = i
   encoded_cmd = cmd.encode("utf-8")
   ser.write(encoded_cmd)
   sleep(0.1)
   print(cmd)
```

#### Code

```py
import serial
import time
from time import sleep
from datetime import datetime

# create list of commands
with open('commands.txt') as commands:
    list_of_commands = [tuple(map(str, i.split(','))) for i in commands]

# open and name log file
date = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
log = open(f'{date}.txt', 'w+')

# serial configuration
info = open('info.txt', 'r')
lines = info.readlines()
port = lines[0].strip('\n')
baud = int(lines[1].strip('\n'))

try:
    # open port
    ser = serial.Serial(port=port, baudrate=baud, timeout=5, parity=serial.PARITY_NONE, stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE, write_timeout=0)

except ConnectionError:
    log.write(''.join('There was a connection error'))

else:
    # run commands
    x = 0
    for lines in list_of_commands:
        ser.close()
        ser.open()
        sleep(2)
        cmd = lines[1]
        encoded_cmd = cmd.encode("utf-8")
        sleep_time = int(lines[0])
        ser.write(encoded_cmd)
        time.perf_counter()
        # log output
        while 1:
            test = ser.readline()
            text = test.decode('utf-8')
            print(text)
            log.write(''.join(text))
            print(time.perf_counter())
            print(time.perf_counter() - x)
            if time.perf_counter() - x > sleep_time:
                x = time.perf_counter()
                ser.flushInput()
                ser.flushOutput()
                break
        print(cmd)
 
    # close port
    ser.close()
    
# close files
log.close()
```

Comment: How can you verify, that the device receives the commands, is there some response or log you expect? Except `no` are there any commands to be read from your file, which? Where did you exclude the header given in your CSV file `commands.txt` ?

Comment: There are more commands to be read from the command file. I just gave the first three lines. I don't have a header on the txt file. I just included sleep_time,cmd\n to show formatting. When the device receives the command, it'll trigger a prompt which would be outputted onto the log.

Comment: It seems like all commands terminate with comma, so do you need comma after no (i.e. `2,no,` ) ?

Comment: The comma is just splitting the sleep_time and the actual command. The comma is removed when I create list_of_commands.

Answer (score 0):

From the question it's obvious that multiple issues are intermingled. The same observation comes when reading the code. So I tried to list some of those I struggled with.

### Issues

#### Try-except-else

What is the intention behind `try .. except .. else` ?

Not sure, its used correctly on purpose here. See [try-except-else explained](https://pythonbasics.org/try-except/#try-else):

> The else clause is executed if and only if no exception is raised. This is different from the finally clause that’s always executed.

#### The serial connection

Why opening and closing inside the loop:

```
        ser.close()
        ser.open()
```

Why the misleading comment:

```
# close server
ser.close()
```

#### Usage of `sleep_time`

What is the purpose of using the first column `sleep_time` of your CSV `commands.txt` inside a conditional break inside you read-loop?

```
sleep_time = int(lines[0])
```

Instead the sleep is fix 2 seconds before sending the command:

```
sleep(2)
```

### How to debug

I would recommend adding some `print` (or log) statements to

- verify the `list_of_commands` has been read correctly
- verify which commands (`cmd` or even `encoded_cmd`) have been sent to the serial output

Comment: I may be misunderstanding try/except/else/finally. I was under the assumption the finally still runs even if there is an exception. I don't want the code in else to execute if it can't open the port. 
I start the loop with ser.close and ser.open because as I was researching the issue, I found this ticket: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30703819/pyserial-port-only-work-the-first-command 
The final close is because the port is left open after the loop breaks.
Sleeptime to be renamed. I'm using it to break out of While 1. Using while ser.readline never broke even when there was nothing.